# create link for each outer list item using HTML CSS JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the user selects one of the dropdowns links it needs to take them to a webpage I need to link the li items 1-4 to a webpage im stuck need help creating the links thanks in advance for your help. Below I have provided the code HTML and CSS and JS code. Thanks again.
(I am adding more text here in order to submit this question so be sure to ignore this part)

```js
'use strict';

(function() {

  var _btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn'),

    _eachBtn = function(callback) {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(_btns, function(elem) {
        callback.call(this, elem);
      });
    },
    _initListener = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      _eachBtn(function(btn) {
        btn.classList.remove('dropdown-open')
      });
      this.classList.toggle('dropdown-open');
    },
    _hideAll = function() {
      _eachBtn(function(btn) {
        btn.classList.remove('dropdown-open');
      });
    };

  _eachBtn(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
      _initListener.call(this, e);
    });

    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      _initListener.call(this, e);
    });
  });

  document.addEventListener('touchend', function() {
    _hideAll();
  });
  
  document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    _hideAll();
  });

})();
```

````css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 15em;
}

.dropdown > .outer-list {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

.dropdown > .outer-list.top {
  align-items: flex-start;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
}

.dropdown > .outer-list.left { justify-content: flex-start; }

.dropdown > .outer-list.bottom {
  align-items: flex-end;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}

.dropdown > .outer-list.right { justify-content: flex-end; }

.dropdown > .outer-list > ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: .2em;
}

.dropdown > .outer-list > ul li {
  padding: .25em 3em;
  margin: .25em;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.35s ease;
}

.dropdown > .outer-list > ul li:hover { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07); }
```
```
.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #03A9F4;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: .15em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50%;
  right: -50%;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

.btn:active:after,
.btn.dropdown-open:after {
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
}

.btn:hover { box-shadow: inset 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }

.btn.dropdown-open + .outer-list {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
````

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="btn">
    Dropdown
  </a>
  <div class="outer-list">
    <ul>
      <li>List item 1</li>
      <li>List item 2</li>
      <li>List item 3</li>
      <li>List item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the links inside the LI tags like so

```
 <div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="btn">
    Dropdown
  </a>
  <div class="outer-list">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.co.uk">List item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.co.uk">List item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.co.uk">List item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.co.uk">List item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yea i did that but creates a box to the left of the text that is clickable and the text is not and if i put the </a> after the List Item then it puts a box around the text. I need to make it so its clickable as is hopefully i explained that correctly

Comment: @ΘΗΣΈΑΣ: see where is the `</a>` now?

Comment: hey thanks yea i saw it issue is the href causes the dropdown to the same color as the btn class trying to figure out how to uncolor the dropdown after linking the dropdown

Comment: thank you @Louys Patrice Bessette. I should have noticed my error.